# SQL: Select distinct items where condition is met

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, relation

I have a relation in a database as follows:

```
constituents                                                         Symbol
[{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"WPM"},{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"AEM"}]      GLD
[{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"XYZ"},{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"ABC"}]      KLE
[{"weight":1.0, "ticker":"TSLA"}]                                    TSLA
[{"weight":1.0, "ticker":"MSFT"}]                                    MSFT
[{"weight":0.4, "ticker":"XYZ"},{"weight":0.6, "ticker":"ABC"}]      KLE
[{"weight":0.3, "ticker":"BBBY"},{"weight":0.7, "ticker":"GME"}]     MEME
```

I want to get the distinct symbols where the constituents column contains more than 1 json in the list. So the outcome should be

`GLD, KLE, MEME`

My attempt is:

`SELECT DISTINCT "Symbol" FROM "MyTable" WHERE JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH("constitutents")>1`

but I get an error: `ERROR:  cannot get array length of a non-array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depemds how our column is defined as JSON or JSONB, so you need to use the appropriate functions

## JSONB

```
CREATE TABLE T2
    ("constituents" JSONB, "Symbol" varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO T2
    ("constituents", "Symbol")
VALUES
    ('[{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"WPM"},{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"AEM"}]', 'GLD'),
    ('[{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"XYZ"},{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"ABC"}]', 'KLE'),
    ('[{"weight":1.0, "ticker":"TSLA"}]', 'TSLA'),
    ('[{"weight":1.0, "ticker":"MSFT"}]', 'MSFT'),
    ('[{"weight":0.4, "ticker":"XYZ"},{"weight":0.6, "ticker":"ABC"}]', 'KLE'),
    ('[{"weight":0.3, "ticker":"BBBY"},{"weight":0.7, "ticker":"GME"}]', 'MEME')
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 6
> ```

```
SELECT "Symbol" FROM T2 WHERE JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH("constituents") > 1
```

| Symbol |
| --- |
| GLD |
| KLE |
| KLE |
| MEME |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nm450jMj)

## Json

```
CREATE TABLE T2
    ("constituents" JSON, "Symbol" varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO T2
    ("constituents", "Symbol")
VALUES
    ('[{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"WPM"},{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"AEM"}]', 'GLD'),
    ('[{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"XYZ"},{"weight":0.5, "ticker":"ABC"}]', 'KLE'),
    ('[{"weight":1.0, "ticker":"TSLA"}]', 'TSLA'),
    ('[{"weight":1.0, "ticker":"MSFT"}]', 'MSFT'),
    ('[{"weight":0.4, "ticker":"XYZ"},{"weight":0.6, "ticker":"ABC"}]', 'KLE'),
    ('[{"weight":0.3, "ticker":"BBBY"},{"weight":0.7, "ticker":"GME"}]', 'MEME')
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 6
> ```

```
SELECT "Symbol" FROM T2 WHERE JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH("constituents") > 1
```

| Symbol |
| --- |
| GLD |
| KLE |
| KLE |
| MEME |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dmApKx6Q)

Comment: It is a jsonb but using your method, I get `ERROR:  cannot get array length of a non-array
`

Comment: which version are you using. as you can see the fiddle works, so it must be you data, if they differ from the example or the Version

Comment: in the fillde this works also for 9.5, so i am guessing you data, is not like the sample

Comment: So the data for the first row in the constituents column is composed as follows: `array [2]` and then for each item in the array `0 {2}` and `1 {2}` and it's a jsonb column

Comment: please try some more data on the sample fiddle and see if you can reconstruct the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it has a comma in it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Symbol" 
FROM "MyTable"
WHERE CONTAINS("constitutents",',')
```

Comment: I am getting the following `ERROR:  function contains(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
`

Comment: Also `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
`